# What is a technical term for "addressing reviewers comments"?

Tags: tech-writing

When collaborating on a document, reviewers will often leave comments. The process is complete once all the comments have been "_________" by the original author.

("Addressed" is the closest thing I've come up with, but I know there is a more formal word here that I'm just forgetting. The thing to note is that not all comments were necessarily "incorporated" into the document, but they have all been reviewed, evaluated, and incorporated as necessary.)

Comment: The stage of responding to comments in workflows is often called something like "revise" or "rework", but they don't apply to the process of evaluating comments, as much as the process of acting upon them. "Read"?

Answer (score 1):

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/consider)
> Consider:
> to think about a particular subject or thing or about doing something or about whether to do something

When acting as a reviewer or editor I expect the author to have *considered* or *taken account of* the reviewers' comments before the work may be considered complete.

Your sentence would then read:
*The process is complete once all the comments have been **considered** by the original author.*
or
*The process is complete once all the comments have been **taken into account** by the original author.*

These are several acceptable phrases deriving from the the notion that the comments have been *considered*, *taken into consideration* or *taken into account*.

> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/synonyms/consider)
> Consider - synonyms:
> take into consideration, take into account, take account of, ... pay regard to

The last two Lexico alternatives need a different word order:
*... once the author has taken account of all the comments*
*... once the author has paid regard to all the comments*

All these constructions tell us that no comments have been ignored by the author, who will have thought about them all, accepting some and altering accordingly, and rejecting others.

Answer (score 1):

**Reviewed**

> A formal assessment or examination of something with the possibility or intention of instituting change if necessary.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/review)

You'll see this in common usage, as in "please review these changes". Microsoft Word uses "Review" as the menu name for going over tracked changes.

Answer (score 1):

*The process is complete once all the comments have been **resolved** by the original author.*

*Resolved* is used in IT world by multiple apps handling review comments on documents or software source code.

Quoting help page for [resolvable-comments-and-threads](https://gitlab-docs.creationline.com/ee/user/discussions/#resolvable-comments-and-threads) in GitLab :

> The need to **resolve** all standard comments or threads prevents you from forgetting to address feedback and lets you hide threads that are no longer relevant.

[GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/reviewing-changes-in-pull-requests/commenting-on-a-pull-request) uses same terminology:

> From this view, you can see which conversations are unresolved, resolved, and outdated. This makes it easy to discover and **resolve** conversations.

Answer (score 0):

I would use **respond to** or **response** in constructing a sentence to express this idea, but to avoid the inelegant combination of two prepositions I would rephrase the example slightly:

> The process is complete once the original author has **responded to** all the comments.

This, I think is better than the passive construction, but if that is to be retained:

> The process is complete once all the comments have received a **response** from the original author.

(If this is a quiz, and I have to fill the gap, it’s “responded to”, and I claim my prize. But “responded to by” is not recommended.)

A response can agree or disagree with a point raised in a comment.

**Drawn from life**

After writing the above, I checked referee’s letters I had received from four different journals in the field of molecular biology:

“…we ask that you *consider* the *points* raised by the referees…
Please either *answer* them in a revised version or *explain* why they are not relevant.”

“I am attaching copies of their *comments* to this e-mail. Please revise your article accordingly, and *provide* a point-by-point *response* with your revised article.”

“Along with any revised files, you must also prepare and *submit a response* clearly outlining all changes made to the manuscript.  Please provide in the "*Author Response*" section, a "point-by-point" summary of how each of the *issues* raised by the reviewer(s) were *addressed*.”

“We would be grateful if you could *address* the comments in a revised manuscript and provide a cover letter giving a point-by-point *response* to the *concerns*.”

So I think I’ll stick with my suggestion.

Comment: Great suggestion, but I know there is a specific technical term that I have heard often (at least in my office).

Comment: @kmote — I see you’ve remembered it. Must say  I’m not  particularly of that disposition. However I suspect it’s a question of “Government proposes, a lawyer disposes”.

Answer (score -2):

OK, my colleague just reminded me of the term I was looking for:

> Dispositioned

Upon reflection, however, I realize now that this term might actually be unique to my field (government procedure writing). However, The [Collins Dictionary entry #2](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/disposition), lists "settlement of affairs" as one definition, which seems reasonably appropriate.

Comment: But why do you think this matches? I couldn't find a relevant definition (not under *disposition*, nor [dispositioned](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Dispositioned)).

Comment: Great question, and I'm a little puzzled too. I've been hearing it for years across several departments in my company, but I'm starting to wonder if it is just an Inigo Montoya situation ("You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means”).

Comment: @kmote Please include the relevant definition and the link to the dictionary within your answer for posterity. Comments are ephemeral.

Comment: Although *disposition* has currency in your organisation, I suggest it is a local usage. I have never encountered it in European, British or Scottish governmental usage, never in the normal process of peer review of hundreds of scientific papers (whether as author, reviewer or editor), and never in more informal botanical editing.

Comment: ... and even Collins doesn't ratify the verb usage. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disposition#Verb) does, but only with the 'To remove or place in a different position.' sense.

Comment: In many document reviews in the IT world, I’ve never encountered this term.